# How to find what is starting another process in Windows

Tags: windows

I have a suspicious process on my windows. It is called dfiou.exe. I can't kill it via process manager- I kill it and then it again appears. I suspect it is virus. How can I find what process is starting it again and again?

Comment: Check `wmic process where name='dfiou.exe' get ParentProcessId`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find many information about processes which also includes Parent of process.